# Does SSRS use JavaScript behind the scenes when Exporting to Adobe PDF files?

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

Does SSRS use JavaScript behind the scenes when Exporting to Adobe PDF files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking.  The PDF file is generated on the server, either in the report viewer control or on the SSRS server depending on your setup.

It does not generate the pdf in javascript if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure how to ask it.  But, our corporate hq made this statement and I wanted to know if it would affect my SSRS reports when I select the PDF option for export.
"Because of imminent risk related to a newly identified vulnerability, use of JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat Reader will be disabled on your office computer"

Comment: It is my understanding that SSRS makes no use of java script inside of the PDF files.  Even if it did, worst case you would just lose some functionality.  However I am pretty sure that the PDF files generated by SSRS are considered static.